# Angular 2 Concat and minify with Grunt

Tags: angular, gruntjs, angular2-template, grunt-contrib-concat

I love using Grunt for concatenating and minifying plugins etc.. can someone please tell me how to do this task on Angular 2's node_modules.. i want to end up with 1 file that is minified and concatenated..  I have tried webpack etc and gulp tutorials but none of them get the jobs done.

Comment: Does that help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/42933220/1160794

Comment: You can simply add Grunt minfiy command in to angular.json file to run on build command

Comment: Also, you say you want to do it on node `node_modules`, but angular already does that: ithe resulting file is `vendor.js`