# How to launch angular prod project without any server?

Tags: angular, ipfs

I want to deploy my angular project in IPFS so I want to know if is possible to launch an angular project without any http server, like static html, css and js template?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about IPFS, but an Angular prod build is just simple HTML + JS files. You can even bundle them [together into one file as well](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4496). An Angular application instance can exist only in the user's browser alone (in Browser mode).

Comment: it seems like building angular project in one file isn't supported directly by the angular CLI, I look for it. thanks :)

Comment: you might need to do a little scripting.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42933220/how-to-get-one-file-as-output-of-angular-cli

I belive you can then copy+paste the .js file contnet into the html directly with a <script> tag - but it might be better to publish the two files or make the .js file available on a separate webserver?

Comment: I need to make all scripts in the index file. to deploy it in IPFS as a single file.

Comment: after you create it, just copy the content from the .js files to the middle of the html file between an `<script>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can publish the angular app as it is. But because there is no web server behind ipfs, you have to use [HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy) in the app routing:

`RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})`

(by default angular uses PathLocationStrategy which requires a web server to serve all nested routes to origin app html file)