# How to chain npm script call after each ng serve build?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm-scripts, concurrently

I'm trying to chain the `ng serve` script call while running but when I've ran this command the second chained script `build-components.js` runs only on first call.
I thought *concurrently* package here would allow both scripts to run in sequence according to docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

What I'm aiming to do is run the `build-components.js` script every time `ng serve` runs (i.e, detects a source change).

*Package.json script*:

```
"build:watch": "concurrently \"ng serve --port 4003\" \"node build-components.js\""
```

*Testing*

```
 concurrently "ng serve --port 4003" "node build-components.js"

[1] node build-components.js exited with code 0
[0] i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:4003/webpack-dev-server/
```

*Question:*

How can you run another npm script after each ng serve build?

I've also had a look at the npm post hooks but this doesn't seem to run the script after `ng serve` has ran either.

http://www.marcusoft.net/2015/08/pre-and-post-hooks-for-npm-scripting.html#hooks-pre-and-post

This is the `build-components.js` script for reference. It copies some extra build files to a public folder for hosting:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const concat = require('concat');

(async function build() {
  const js = [
    './dist/app/runtime-es2015.js',
    './dist/app/main-es2015.js',
    './dist/app/scripts.js',
  ];
  const css = ['./dist/app/styles.css'];

  await fs.ensureDir('components');
  await concat(js, 'components/component.js');
  await concat(css, 'components/component.css');
})();
```

Comment: what are you trying to do bigger picture?

Comment: Another Angular  app is requesting the build files from this app at runtime. So I'm trying to pretty much `ng build && node build-elements.js` automatically as the developer saves their work. Does that make sense?

Comment: So really I'd like to be able to do the following `ng build --watch && node build-components.js` but it seems like you said above ng build does not complete when run in watch?

Comment: Hmm, you can tweak `angular.json` to create a configuration with a different output folder (or change the default output folder).  I don't see anything built in to concat the files.  You can possibly use [ngx-build-plus](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus) to do that but I don't know for certain.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42933220/how-to-get-one-file-as-output-of-angular-cli) seemed to suggest that would be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.  `ng serve` does not complete when run in watch mode so chaining items to run after it will have no effect.  The `serve` command has no hooks for this.

Comment: Yeah I see `ngx-build-plus` does have a reference app here to demonstrate single bundle build. Looks to be half the build time of `ng-build`

Comment: Kind of hacked this by using the npm package `watch` to run a build with `ngx build plus` build on every source file change. It is a couple of seconds quicker than plain old `ng build` as I'm outputting a single bundle. But no way as quick as an `ng serve` which I understand is because `ng serve` doesn't output the bundle to disk instead it stores the bundle in memory? @Pace

Comment: @BrianJ `ng serve` is an incremental build.  The first build should be about the same speed as `ng build` but subsequent changes do not require a full recompile.  Yes, this is achieved by holding not just the bundle but the build context in memory already parsed and tokenized.  Is there any way you can still use `ngx build plus` and pass in the `--watch` flag?

Comment: Nope running with `--watch` flag behaves same way to default `ng build` it doesn't exit. So the second script doesn't run. For example `ng-build --watch && node build-components.js`